# Exception while connecting to proxy through quickfix

Tags: proxy, quickfix, quickfixj

I am trying to connect to a proxy through quickfix/j initiator. I have the below properties in the initiator settings:

```
[SESSION]
ConnectionType=initiator
TargetCompID=XXX
SocketConnectHost=<destination domain name>
SocketConnectPort=XXXX
SessionQualifier=xyz
ProxyType=socks
ProxyVersion=5
ProxyHost=<proxy domain name>
ProxyPort=1080
```

But, I am getting below exception while creating proxyRequest. Any leads will be greatly appreciated.

```
[NioProcessor-2] ERROR org.apache.mina.proxy.AbstractProxyLogicHandler - Unable to send Socks request:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: SocksProxyRequest object has no suitable endpoint information
    at org.apache.mina.proxy.handlers.socks.Socks5LogicHandler.encodeProxyRequestPacket(Socks5LogicHandler.java:137) ~[mina-core.jar:?]
    at org.apache.mina.proxy.handlers.socks.Socks5LogicHandler.writeRequest(Socks5LogicHandler.java:292) ~[mina-core.jar:?]
    at org.apache.mina.proxy.handlers.socks.Socks5LogicHandler.doHandshake(Socks5LogicHandler.java:88) ~[mina-core.jar:?]
```

Quick update: 
The connection works if I replace the destination domain name with the IP. Any ideas how to make it work for the domain name?

Comment: Which version of QuickFIX/J are you using? I'm asking this, as I've read that some fixes were done at some point so you require at least version 1.6.4.

Comment: Using the same version

Comment: Also just updated the question with an update, please check that as well. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the domain name can be resolved from the instance you are running your program from? On Windows platforms, you can use `nslookup` to verify that.

Comment: `The connection works if I replace the destination domain name with the IP` There in lies your problem. The domain name cannot be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

for anyone passing this question in future, an open issue in Apache Mina requires local name resolution, while this would actually be the proxies task

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DIRMINA-963

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).